# Could not initialize class sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig$ProviderLoader

Tags: java

Springboot occassionally occur following errors:

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig$ProviderLoader

```
at java.base/sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig$3.run(ProviderConfig.java:244)

at java.base/sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig$3.run(ProviderConfig.java:238)

at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

at java.base/sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig.doLoadProvider(ProviderConfig.java:238)

at java.base/sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig.getProvider(ProviderConfig.java:218)

at java.base/sun.security.jca.ProviderList.getProvider(ProviderList.java:266)

at java.base/sun.security.jca.ProviderList$ServiceList.tryGet(ProviderList.java:511)

at java.base/sun.security.jca.ProviderList$ServiceList$1.hasNext(ProviderList.java:565)

at java.base/javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory.nextSpi(SecretKeyFactory.java:301)

at java.base/javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory.<init>(SecretKeyFactory.java:121)

at java.base/javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(SecretKeyFactory.java:168)

at com.kingbase8.shaded.com.ongres.scram.common.ScramMechanisms.saltedPassword(ScramMechanisms.java:155)

at com.kingbase8.shaded.com.ongres.scram.common.ScramFunctions.saltedPassword(ScramFunctions.java:59)

at com.kingbase8.shaded.com.ongres.scram.client.ScramSession$ClientFinalProcessor.<init>(ScramSession.java:196)

at com.kingbase8.shaded.com.ongres.scram.client.ScramSession$ClientFinalProcessor.<init>(ScramSession.java:163)

at com.kingbase8.shaded.com.ongres.scram.client.ScramSession$ServerFirstProcessor.clientFinalProcessor(ScramSession.java:130)
```

JDK information as following:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EA35.png)

Comment: Note. The source code line who throws the exception is https://github.com/openjdk/jdk11u/blob/jdk-11+28/src/java.base/share/classes/sun/security/jca/ProviderConfig.java#L244

Answer (score 0):

Ah, please try to search the log, it is possible a `ExceptionInInitializerError` was happened before, so this time the JVM throws `NoClassDefFoundError` directly because it was failed last time.

Need to get the call stack of the original `ExceptionInInitializerError` (if it exists) in order to fix this issue.

Related codes and links

- https://github.com/openjdk/jdk11u/blob/jdk-11+28/src/java.base/share/classes/sun/security/jca/ProviderConfig.java#L308 - the class `ProviderConfig$ProviderLoader` was defined inside OpenJDK 11 so it is not likely to a Java `classpath` issue
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/5756989/2412606 - See definition of `NoClassDefFoundError` here. thanks to [@oldpeculier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/358475/oldpeculier) and [@jared](https://stackoverflow.com/users/44757/jared)

Comment: I add configruation -Djava.security.debug="jca" in server start script and not found ExceptionInInitializerError log. how to fixing this error?

Answer (score 0):

For this problem not very clear why occur. in order to fix the problem. we can  manual use Security.addSecurity method to load jca or analogous component again. like BouncyCastle. now it work fine for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I was using Java 11 and the project was build using Java 1.8. Once I switched to Java 1.8 it worked fine